# Use AppRTC with a custom server

Tags: android, webrtc

I've successfully build the AppRTC for android and I'm able to make videocalls providing the address of the demo app ( https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=XXXXXXXX )

My question is, how can I make this app work with a custom WebRTC server OR with another WebRTC app ( e.g. https://talky.io/)

I'm a little bit confused about how to achieve this.
I've also followed the tutorials [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab) and I'm able to make calls between desktop browser but I have no idea how to connect from the android app.

P.S.

If someone is interested I've built the app following the following links:

[WebRTC : ninja build not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047559/webrtc-ninja-build-not-working) (see the comments)

http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/

Comment: I am trying to build a webrtc application for android but i'm stuck...
Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I want to deploy my own server. what did you use? Can you guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve webrtc with your own server.

Several steps to follow:

1.Build your own HTTP server to provide the html service(i.e. the main page of your webRTC project instead of apprtc main page). In this step I use node.js and node-static(https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static).

2.Build your own signalling server. PeerJS is a good choice. Read the doc files. Also, code you HTML file to support peerjs.

Here is an example of peerjs implementation. It helped me a lot

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/peerjs

Goodluck!

Comment: Right now I have a better understanding of how WebRTC works, I'm building from zero signaling server with node and socket.io.
Then I'll try to do it on android.

Comment: Did you manage to set it up using the apprtc client + peerjs server?

Comment: @Ignas I managed to build up a webrtc example with peerjs and my own HTML/JS code. I did not use the apprtc as the client.

Comment: did yu succeed in building apprtc with custom socket io server??? Even i tried accessing signaling.simplewebrtc.com signaling server by deploying it locally. I used socket io and engine io wrapper. but my socket request is rejected.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can deploy web version of https://apprtc.appspot.com/ to your own server.

It's written on GAE (Google App Engine) - http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/js/apprtc/
This has been moved to branches folder http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/branches/3.53/samples/js/apprtc/

Just register GAE account https://appengine.google.com/ and deploy this web app to it.

Next - you can connect WebRTC Android sample to you own GAE server - https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/examples/android/src/org/appspot/apprtc/AppRTCDemoActivity.java

Find line

```
roomInput.setText("https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=");
```

and replace apprtc server name

Comment: First, thanks for answers, I have a question:
- How exactly I can deploy that app on my own server?

Comment: Please read this https://appengine.google.com . You will find all info how to deploy GAE app to your server

Comment: How to run it with out GAE? Because with GAE same http/https services we have to pay, we do not want to pay for it. How can i we use it in that case without GAE?

Comment: It's a bit hard - you have to completely rewrite sample and replace GAE with something else as a signalling.

Comment: The links are down.