# How to build WebRTC for Android?

Tags: android, build, webrtc

How can be build webrtc library for Android as far as under webrtc/trunk/ directory there is no /build directory?

But we need to run this command: 
$ source ./build/android/envsetup.sh

and as a result of this I always have:

bash: ./build/android/envsetup.sh: No such file or directory

so how can this be build?

P.S. in project directory there is a .gitignore file which contains /build directory so what I missed in all tutorials that said to run command $ source ./build/android/envsetup.sh ?

Comment: Did you forget the `gclient runhooks --force` step?

Comment: Building webrtc for android from source is a nightmare, I succeded only once and now I'm not able to build it anymore.
However I used those links

http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/ AND

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047559/webrtc-ninja-build-not-working (see comments)

Good luck!

Comment: I think you have to look into this article if you still needed it. [Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC)